# Obtaining unknowns from a matrix

Tags: matrices

Given matrices
A = $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & 1 \\ x & 2 & y \\ 1 & y & 3 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

B = $$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -3 & z \\ -3 & 2 & -3 \\ z & -3 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$
Obtain x, y and z if matrix AB is symmetric.

I know the long way by comparing $ (AB)^T = AB $. Is there any short method of doing this since the given matrices are symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A,B$ are symmetric, you have to have $AB = (AB)^T = B^T A^T = BA$.

Then, you can write out the equations $[AB]_{ij} = [BA]_{ij}$ for different values of $ij$ (hopefully you pick three good values of $i,j$; you need to get 3 linearly independent equations to solve for the 3 unknowns) of $i,j$ by noting $[AB]_{ij}$ is the $i$-th row of $A$ dotted with the $j$-th column of $B$, and $[BA]_{ij}$ is the $i$-th row of $B$ dotted with the $j$-th column of $A$. If you got 3 linearly independent equations, you just have to solve them and you're done.

But its probably easier just to write out $AB$, $BA$ and then match the equations.

Comment: Thanks for answer...But that's what I was doing. i was just wondering if there is any other trick to solve it in no time.. Anyway thanks!